# Redirect if query has no result

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I've made a page with an input which connects to this view:

```
class SearchResultView(ListView):
    model = RecipeSet

    template_name = 'core/set_result.html'
    context_object_name = 'recipe_set'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = RecipeSet.objects.filter(
            Q(set_name__exact=query)
        )
        if object_list.exists():
            return object_list
        else:
            return redirect('core:dashboard')
```

I've used set_name__exact for this query and want to redirect users if the search returned no objects, how do I go about this? I've tried to use an if/else statement to check the objects but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`.get_queryset(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method should return a `QuerySet`, not a list, tuple, `HttpResponse`, etc.

You can however alter the behavior, by setting the `allow_empty` attribute to `allow_empty = False`, and override the `dispatch` method such that in case of a `Http404`, you redirect:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class SearchResultView(ListView):
    allow_empty = False
    model = RecipeSet
    template_name = 'core/set_result.html'
    context_object_name = 'recipe_set'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return RecipeSet.objects.filter(
            set_name=self.request.GET.get('q')
        )

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return redirect('core:dashboard')
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I'm not sure how I didn't come across allow_empy when I was looking through the docs... Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just change the .exists to .count:

```
class SearchResultView(ListView):
model = RecipeSet

template_name = 'core/set_result.html'
context_object_name = 'recipe_set'

def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = RecipeSet.objects.filter(
        Q(set_name__exact=query)
    )
    if object_list.count():
        return object_list
    else:
        return redirect('core:dashboard')
```

Comment: But by returning a `HttpRedirectResponse` (by the `redirect` call), this will error, since `get_queryset` is not supposed to return something else.

Comment: I personally prefer `.count() > 0`.

Comment: @Uri: well `.exists()` sometimes is faster than `.count()`, since if there is no index, exists can stop from the moment one record is found, whereas the `.count()` in that case should keep searching for more records to count the total number of items.